# Why is my data set being shortened when I page in my asp gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Its a standard gridview:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvAlerts" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    DataKeyNames="Id" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
    OnRowDataBound="gvAlerts_RowDataBound"
    OnSelectedIndexChanging="gvAlerts_SelectedIndexChanging"
    OnRowDeleting="gvAlerts_RowDeleting"
    EmptyDataText="There are no alerts to manage."
    PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true"
    PagerSettings-Position="TopAndBottom"
    PagerSettings-Visible="true"
    PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast"
    OnPageIndexChanging="gvAlerts_PageIndexChanging">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="" DataField="ContractEntity"
            SortExpression="Supplier" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Reference" DataField="Reference"
            SortExpression="Reference" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="Date"
            SortExpression="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Contact Person" DataField="Username"
            SortExpression="Username" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="End Date" DataField="EndDate"
            SortExpression="EndDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Value" DataField="Value"
            SortExpression="Value" DataFormatString="R{0:# ### ###.00}" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Category" DataField="ContractCategory"
            SortExpression="Category" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" SelectText="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i>" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteText="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I can't seem to get the paging working right though.

In the code below I've limited the data to 80 records (for testing purposes). It appears that the data does actually page over when I go to a different page, but that's not all it does; there is also always less data returned every time until eventually paging is no longer possible because there aren't enough records to bind to the gridview.

```
private List<Alert> _alerts { get; set; }

protected void gvAlerts_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvAlerts.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    try
    {
        PageData(e.NewPageIndex);
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
    {
        // Get all Alerts data again since the collection was apparently
        // emptied on postback.
        _alerts = GetAlerts();
        PageData(e.NewPageIndex);
    }
}

private void PageData(int pageIndex)
{
    List<Alert> alerts = _alerts;
    if (pageIndex >= 2)
    {
        alerts = _alerts.Skip(pageIndex * gvAlerts.PageSize).Take(gvAlerts.PageSize).ToList();
    }

    gvAlerts.DataSource = BuildGridViewModel(alerts);
    gvAlerts.DataBind();
}

private List<AlertListViewModel> BuildGridViewModel(List<Alert> alerts)
{
    var model = new List<AlertListViewModel>();
    var u = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

    using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        foreach (Alert alert in alerts)
        {
            // Due to poor database design, these queries are unavoidable.
            var contract = db.Contracts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == alert.ContractId);
            var category = db.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == contract.CategoryId).Name;
            var entity = db.ContractEntities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == contract.ContractEntityId).Name;

            model.Add(new AlertListViewModel
            {
                // Map model properties.
            });
        }
    }
    return model;
}
```

I understand that the `.Skip()` and `.Take()` are probably what's shortening the data set but without those, how am I to change the data that is currently visible on the gridview?

I'm missing something here. What is it? How do I get this gridview paging without losing any data?

Comment: gvAlerts.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex; thats all you need, you don't need to use skip or take.

Comment: @InitLipton that changes the page in the gridview but the data doesn't change

Answer (score 1):

The downside of the GridVIew is that all the records are retrieved every time and/or all stored in ViewState. So if you want to use Linq create your own paging method. Below a quick example of how this can be done.
If you still want to use the build-in paging, follow the comment of `InitLipton`

```
List<Book> books;
int pageSize = 10;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //fill the collection
    books = fillBooks();

    //create the dynamic pager buttons, this needs to be done on every page load
    createPager();

    //bind the grid for the first time without postback
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        bindGrid(0);
    }
}


private void bindGrid(int offSet)
{
    //bind the right amount of items to the grid
    GridView1.DataSource = books.Skip(offSet).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}


private void createPager()
{
    //loop for every x items in the collection
    for (int i = 0; i < (books.Count / pageSize); i++)
    {
        //create a linkbutton
        LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();

        //add the properties
        lb.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
        lb.CommandArgument = i.ToString();

        //bind the command method
        lb.Command += Lb_Command;

        //add the linkbutton to the page
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lb);

        //add some spacing
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "&nbsp;" });
    }
}


private void Lb_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    //rebind the grid with the next 10 items
    bindGrid(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) * 10);
}
```

And the aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:GridView>
<br />
<br />
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```